# jQuery - limiting droppable capacity in a sub-list within an overall sortable list

Tags: jquery, html-lists, jquery-ui-sortable, droppable

So yeah, this one might be a little bit confusing - I have a sortable list, within this list I will have sublists which are also sortable and which can accept list elements from the overarching list inside of them (nesting).  What I need to do is prevent these inner lists from accepting more elements after they reach a certain number of child elements.

This is what I've tried so far:

javascript side:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".sortable").sortable({
        connectWith: ".sortable",
        revert:true
    }).disableSelection();

    $(".inner").droppable({
        accept: function(d) {
            // this here refers to the inner list, correct?
            if ($(this).children().length > 1) {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                return true;
            }
        },
        drop: function() {
        // blah blah blah
        }
    });
});
```

HTML side:

```
        <ul id="mainlist" class="sortable">
            <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
                   <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default">
                Place here:[[  &nbsp;&nbsp;
                <ul class="sortable inner">
                           <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
                </ul>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;
                ]]
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Does anyone out there see something I'm doing wrong? Is there just a better way of doing this?

Comment: I'm not sure why your method doesn't work. I'm not sure what I would do would be any better. If I were tasked with this, I would add a function to the drop event so that after a drop it would check it's children and if the limit has been reached then disable the drop target. That way if you have any feedback enabled the user can tell before they drop if it will work or not.

Comment: I was thinking of going to something similar - just noting where the dragged element was in the first place and then putting it back there directly if the number of children is too high.  It seems very inelegant and I'm hoping there's a better way out there somewhere.